# Can nRF52 simultaneously use Bluetooth and act as USB HID Keyboard?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, hid

I want to ask something related to the use of the nRF52 as a HID keyboard (USB host).

I have already played around with the SDK example ble_app_hids_keyboard and tried to understand it as much as I could.

Now I want to use to use the nRF52 as a bluetooth dongle. On one hand it has to be able to connect to another device (another nRF52 - serving as the keyboard) via bluetooth and on the other hand transfer this data to a PC as a USB.

So the question is whether the nRF52 can be configured like that, act as a USB host and communicate via bluetooth to another device at the same time?

I have some knowledge on how the USB and HID protocols works, however it is not enough to manage to succeed on this issue.

---

Thanks for the replies.

I did not mean to connect a keyboard to the nRF52832. I meant to have the nRF52832 act as a keyboard, which I have already done and then use its Bluetooth capability to connect it to a USB dongle, which then would transfer the data to the PC.

My problem is the dongle. I thought that I could maybe use another nRF52832 to implement the dongle, but I am having trouble with it. However, after some research, ai figured out that one of the most popular USB dongle chips is the CSR8510.

However I do not know how to program it. All I could find is that people have bought some 500€ development kits which they use to program the chips.

ai would like to ask you guys if you know any method to program the CSR8510 wothout having the development kit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bluetooth HID Profiles do exist. Doesn't Nordic Semi have examples of this?

Comment: If you want this microcontroller to connect to a PC and emulate a USB keyboard you need it to be a USB device, not a USB host. The PC is the host.

Comment: The nRF52832 does not have USB at all, the nRF52840 does

Answer (score 1):

nRF52 has only a device type USB controller, so it is not possible to connect an USB keyboard directly to it.

You would have to use an external USB host controller chip or try something like V-USB (but it will most likely be impossible to use reliably because of the Bluetooth stack timing requirements).

It would be quite easy to interface with a PS/2 keyboard though...

Comment: I think the OP is confused with their terminology - they want the nRF52 to be a device, not a host.